# What happens in the reaction of ammonium dichromate and mercury(II) thiocyanate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I found [this reaction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzjPva_MUAg) of $\ce{NH4Cr2O7 + Hg(SCN)2 ->[\Delta]\ ?}$ on youtube, and I'm curious as to how it works. I tried searching online, but didn't find much on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of two reactions.  The first is the [ammonium dichromate vocano](http://www.angelo.edu/faculty/kboudrea/demos/volcano/volcano.htm) and the second is called [Pharaoh's snakes](http://chemistry.about.com/od/fireworksprojects/a/pharaohs-snakes.htm).

### The volcano

The reaction occurring here is: $$\ce{(NH4)2Cr2O7(s) -> Cr2O3(s) + N2(g) + 4 H2O(g)}$$  The reference above provides several pictures and a description of the chemistry.

### Pharaoh's snakes

Again, the reference above describes what is happening, so only a summary of the chemical reactions is given here:
$$\ce{2 Hg(SCN)2->2 HgS + CS2 + C3N4}$$ $$\ce{CS2 + 3O2 -> CO2 + 2SO2}$$ $$\ce{2C3N4->3(CN)2 + N2}$$ $$\ce{HgS + O2->Hg + SO2}$$

Pharaoh's snakes is a rather hazardous demonstration and should not be performed without the proper ventilation, protective gear and waste disposal equipment.

Comment: Which $C_3N_4$ isomer forms preferentially? [This list of carbon nitrides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nitride) provides such options as beta carbon nitride, graphitic carbon nitride, dicyanodiazomethane, nitrogen tricyanide and carbon bis(cyanamide).